# Selecting one of a hundred items with two drop down lists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have ten categories and each of those has ten subcategories. I need to let the user select a subcategory but I don't want to put 100 options in a single drop down. My thought was to have a category drop down with the ten categories and also a subcategory drop down. Depending on what category is chosen from the first drop down, the subcategory drop down is populated with the ten subcategories for that category.  So the user can pick one of a hundred subcategories with two selections.

I can't do  this with PHP since when the page is loaded and the PHP is run, it isn't known what category will be chosen. I'm thinking that the category selection has to trigger some Ajax that brings down the subcategory options for the chosen category and places them in  the subcategory drop down.  Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to do  this?

Comment: _"I have ten categories and each of those has ten subcategories. I need to let the user select a subcategory but I don't want to put 100 options in a single drop down."_ Would that be ten `option` elements at each `select` element , not 100 `option` elements in single `select` element ?

Comment: Yes, ten option elements at each select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load subcategories with json_encode or ajax then use js to remove and append the options on the select change event.

Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LFB2cxFQaNByiE6MwS7B?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="selectCategory">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
  </select>
  <select id="subCategories">
    <option value="1">1-1</option>
    <option value="2">1-2</option>
    <option value="3">1-3</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    // load subcategories with json_encode or ajax
    var subcategories = [{
      category: '1',
      val: 1,
      text: '1-1'
    }, {
      category: '1',
      val: 2,
      text: '1-2'
    }, {
      category: '1',
      val: 3,
      text: '1-3'
    }, {
      category: '2',
      val: 1,
      text: '2-1'
    }, {
      category: '2',
      val: 2,
      text: '2-2'
    }, {
      category: '2',
      val: 3,
      text: '2-3'
    }, {
      category: '3',
      val: 1,
      text: '3-1'
    }, ];


    $("#selectCategory")
      .change(function() {
        var category = this.value;

        $("#subCategories")
          .find('option')
          .remove();

        subcategories.forEach(function(s) {
          if (s.category === category) {
            $("#subCategories")
              .append('<option value="' + s.val + '">' + s.text + '</option>');
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```